# MVC RESTful Service Authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, rest, oauth, authorization

I am in the process of re-writing some very outdated .NET 2.0 SOAP web services for my company.  So I am rewriting them using MVC3 RESTful.  This method would simplify the usage of our services for our client base (over 500 clients using our current SOAP services) who are on multiple platforms and languages.

I am looking for a BETTER method of authorization for the RESTful services, than what the previous developer used for our .NET 2.0 SOAP web services (he basically just had the client pass in a GUID as a parameter and matched it in code behind).

I have looked into oAuth and I want to use it, HOWEVER, I have been told, from my superiors, that this method is TOO complicated for the "level" of clients that connect to our services and want me to find another simpler way for them to connect but still have authorization.  Most of our clients have BASIC to no knowledge of programming (either we helped them get their connection setup OR they hired some kid to do it for them).  This is another reason that the superiors want a different method, because we can't have all 500+ (plus 5-10 new clients a day) asking for help on how to implement oAuth.

So, is there another way to secure the MVC3 services other than passing a preset GUID?

I have looked into using Windows Authentication on the services site, but is this really logical for 500+ clients to use?

Is there an easy and secure method of authorizing multiple users on multiple platforms to use the MVC3 RESTful services that a end-client can implement very easily?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want anything too complicated, have a look at [Basic HTTP Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). If you use it over SSL then it should be safe enough and also easy enough to implement for your clients. The Twitter API actually used this up until a few months ago when they switched to OAuth.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will look into this.  You wouldn't happen have some sites that talk about how to implement a good basic auth model using MVC2/3?  I'll google what I can, but never hurts to ask. :)

Comment: This is a good article on using Basic Authentication with MVC http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/basic-authentication-with-asp-net-webapi/

Answer (score 0):

You want to distinguish between authentication and authorization. What you are looking for is authentication and indeed as [Caps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140514/caps) suggests, the easiest way may be to use HTTP BASIC authentication along with SSL to make the password is not compromised.

You could look into other means of authentication e.g. DIGEST or more advanced using ADFS or SAML (ADFS could be compelling since you're in .NET). Have a look at OpenID Connect too - it is strongly supported by Google and has great support.

Once you are done with that, you may want to consider authorization - if you need it that is - to control what a given client can do on a given resource / item / record. For that you can use claims-based authorization as provided in the .NET framework or if you need finer-grained authorization, look into XACML.

OAuth wouldn't really solve your issue since OAuth is about delegation of authorization i.e. I let Twitter write to my Facebook account on my behalf.

HTH